# Object values change when added to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, time

When trying to create an ArrayList of Timer objects (Timer is a self defined class), all of the objects are changing to the last initialized object before I add them to the ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Timer> timerlist1 = new ArrayList<Timer>();
    LocalDateTime current = LocalDateTime.now();
    Timer time1 = new Timer(current,45);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time1));
    Timer time2 = Timer.getNextTimer(time1);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time2));
    Timer time3 = Timer.getNextTimer(time2);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time3));
    Timer time4 = Timer.getNextTimer(time3);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time4));
    Timer time5 = Timer.getNextTimer(time4);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time5));

    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time1)+"0");
    timerlist1.add(time1);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time1)+"a");
    timerlist1.add(time2);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time2));
    timerlist1.add(time3);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time3));
    timerlist1.add(time4);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time4));
    timerlist1.add(time5);
    System.out.println(Timer.getFormattedTime(time5));
```

The code above prints the following in the console

```
22:24
23:9
23:54
0:39
1:24
1:240
1:24a
1:24
1:24
1:24
1:24
```

The ArrayList should contain

```
22:24
23:9
23:54
0:39
1:24
```

but instead it contains 1:24 for all indeces

This is the Timer class

```
  import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Timer extends Schedule
{
    public  ArrayList<Timer> timers;
    static LocalDateTime start;
    long duration;
    static LocalDateTime end;

    public Timer(){}
    public Timer(LocalDateTime start, long duration)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.end = start.plusMinutes(duration);

    }
    public LocalDateTime getStart()
    {
        return start;

    }
    public static Timer getNextTimer(Timer timer)
    {
        start = end;
        Timer i = new Timer(start,45);
        return i;
    }

    public void shortenDuration(long duration)
    {
        long d = duration;
        this.end = start.plusMinutes(d); 
    }
    public LocalDateTime getEndTime()
    {
         return end;
    }
    public void startAt(LocalDateTime end)
    {
        start=end;
    }
    public static String getFormattedTime(Timer timer)
    {
        int hour = start.getHour();
        int minutes = start.getMinute();
        return(String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(minutes));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `start` field is static so it's the same for all objects you created. The last one being 1:24. Change start so it isn't static.

```
ArrayList<Timer> timerlist1 = new ArrayList<Timer>();
    LocalDateTime current = LocalDateTime.now();
    Timer time1 = new Timer(current,45);
    System.out.println(time1.getFormattedTime(time1));
    Timer time2 = time1.getNextTimer(time1);
    System.out.println(time2.getFormattedTime(time2));
    Timer time3 = time2.getNextTimer(time2);
    System.out.println(time3.getFormattedTime(time3));
    Timer time4 = time3.getNextTimer(time3);
    System.out.println(time4.getFormattedTime(time4));
    Timer time5 = time4.getNextTimer(time4);
    System.out.println(time5.getFormattedTime(time5));

    System.out.println(time1.getFormattedTime(time1)+"0");
    timerlist1.add(time1);
    System.out.println(time1.getFormattedTime(time1)+"a");
    timerlist1.add(time2);
    System.out.println(time2.getFormattedTime(time2));
    timerlist1.add(time3);
    System.out.println(time3.getFormattedTime(time3));
    timerlist1.add(time4);
    System.out.println(time4.getFormattedTime(time4));
    timerlist1.add(time5);
    System.out.println(time5.getFormattedTime(time5));
```

Then the Timer class

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Timer
{
public  ArrayList<Timer> timers;
private LocalDateTime start;
long duration;
private LocalDateTime end;

public Timer(){}
public Timer(LocalDateTime start, long duration)
{
    this.start = start;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.end = start.plusMinutes(duration);

}
public LocalDateTime getStart()
{
    return start;

}
public Timer getNextTimer(Timer timer)
{
    start = end;
    Timer i = new Timer(start,45);
    return i;
}

public void shortenDuration(long duration)
{
    long d = duration;
    this.end = start.plusMinutes(d); 
}
public LocalDateTime getEndTime()
{
     return end;
}
public void startAt(LocalDateTime end)
{
    start=end;
}
public String getFormattedTime(Timer timer)
{
    int hour = start.getHour();
    int minutes = start.getMinute();
    return(String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(minutes));
}
}
```

Comment: but when static is removed, Timer.getNextTimer(time#) produces an error saying it cannot make a static reference to a nonstatic method

Comment: you need to create a new `Timer` object to call `getNextTimer(time)` rather then calling it from `Timer.getNextTimer(time)`

Comment: `end` probably shouldn't be `static` either. `this.end` is a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: exactly sorry about that was taking it one problem at a time

Comment: `Timer timer1 = new Timer();

timer.getNextTimer(time);`

Comment: still getting "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getNextTimer(Timer) from the type Timer"

Comment: `public static Timer getNextTimer(Timer timer)` remove static from here

Comment: how are you calling it? `Timer time2 = Timer.getNextTimer(time1);` should be Timer time2 = time1.getNextTimer(time1);

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: ive added the changes i made to your code that work for me. try them out and let me know what you think